# How to cancel a gitignore from a parent level directory

Tags: git

Having a git repository based on the following directory structure:

```
DIR_A 
      +------DIR_B
      +------DIR_C
      +------DIR_D
      +------DIR_E
```

Having DIR_A have a .gitignore file that ignores "*.bin"

I want that **.gitignore** to be applicable to all subdirectory structures except **DIR_E**. I don't want to set a gitignore that is hardcoding all paths, since more could be added and things would require maintenance and therefore potential mistakes.... So the preferrable way is to have a single .gitignore that excludes DIR_E...

This is what I tried, but it does not seem to work:

*.gitignore (content under DIR_A)* :

```
*.bin
!DIR_E
```

Any ideas why this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ignoring files rather than folders:

```
*.bin
!DIR_E/*.bin
```

Comment: Somehow it does not work :git add DIR_E/*.bin
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:

Comment: What does `git check-ignore -v dir_E/aFile.bin` returns?

Comment: The git check-ignore command was indeed very helpful. In the end I realized your suggestion was effective. thnks